# Pulling YAML parameters into a LaTeX preamble for a RMarkdwon document

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I freely admit I know pretty much no LaTeX, so this may be a very basic question.

My company produces reports using RMarkdown.  To apply styling, including a title page, there is a separate `preamble.tex` file which defines them.

However, a number of values in the `preamble.tex` file are hard coded.  Here's an example of the result:

[image]

However, what I would like to do is pass these "from tex" values in as parameters from the RMarkdown code (presumably as YAML values?).  Is this possible?  If so, how?

If it helps, I've uploaded the code used to run the above (along with a copy of the PDF it generates) here: http://mm-c.me/work/RMarkdown-LaTeX/

Answer (score 2):

That's not very easy, but you can do it by modifying the Pandoc template.

The default templates for LaTeX output are in `system.file("rmd/latex", package = "rmarkdown")`.  Unless you have quite an old version of Pandoc, you probably want the one named `default-1.17.0.2.tex`.  (The number is the Pandoc version.)

As described on this page:  https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/template-pandoc.html, you can modify this template to include additional parameters.

Normally, your

```
includes:
  in_header: preamble.tex
```

would put the `preamble.tex` file just before `\begin{document}`, so what you can do is put a copy of it there yourself, replacing each of the arguments like `title from tex` with Pandoc variables like `$titlefromtex$`, e.g.

```
\fancyhead[L]{\color{clientdark}\small $titlefromtex$ \textbar{ } $periodfromtex$}
```

Save the new file in `template.tex`, then in your YAML, put in top level arguments with matching names and a `pdf_document` argument naming the template, e.g.

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: true
    template: template.tex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
titlefromtex: The Title
periodfromtex: The Period
versionfromtex: The Version
descriptionfromtex: The Description
```